# Symfony 5 : how to add data to a user authenticated in a session, using OneToMany relation?

Tags: symfony, session, foreign-keys

I want to add data to the strategy table via the *title* field, and relate it to the user authenticated in a session with the *user_id* foreign key.

The code below adds data to the strategy table with the relation working, but via a *select option* (choice_label) coded in my FormType file, listing all the users in my view.

**I want to replace that *select option* by a code which gets the user authenticated in the session  instead.**

I looked into the [Security](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#fetch-the-user-in-a-template) and [Session](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html) parts of the documentation, but couldn't make it work.

My tables :[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYJdl.png)

My Controller file:

```
public function create(Strategy $strategy = null, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $strategy = new Strategy();
    
    $form = $this->createForm(StrategyType::class, $strategy);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $em->persist($strategy);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute("frStrategy");
    }

    return $this->render('strategy/updateStrategy.html.twig', [
        "strategy" => $strategy,
        "form" => $form->createView()
    ]);
```

My FormType file:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('user', EntityType::class,[
            'class' => User::class,
            'choice_label' => 'username'
        ])
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either pass the current user to form in an option or inject the security component in the form and use it from there. I think it kinda weird to put a select if you know you'll always have only one option in it but that's another subject.

```
private $security;

public function __construct(Security $security)
{
    $this->security = $security
}    

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('user', EntityType::class,[
            'class' => User::class,
            'choice_label' => 'username',
            'choices' => [$this->security->getUser()],
        ])
    ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million time, your solution worked. You can even remove the 'choice_label' => 'username' since as you said, it's not relevant. I am new to stackoverflow, can I do something else besides marking your answer as positive to thank you ?

Comment: Upvoting the answer if you can with your level, if you can't that's is fine, glad to help ;)

Comment: Thank you. One more thing, I am trying to get rid of the select in my view caused by the 'choices' option. I tried to use a HiddenType::class with the 'data' option, but I couldn't make it work (error : Expected argument of type "App\Entity\User or null", "string" given at property path "user". ). Which form type and option could I use instead of EntityType and choices, to get the user authenticated without rendering it in my view ?